# Magento 2 : Handle quantity below zero

Tags: magento2, quantity

By default, Magento 2 doesn't allow you to give a product a negative quantity:

[image: qty below 0]

2 questions:

- Why is this?
- How can I change this core functionality and what other things might it affect?

I've already looked at where this limit is set, but I can't find it. If I look at `module-catalog-inventory/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`, I see some configuration about this field, but nowhere a limit set.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. 
In **Use Config Settings** there is option for **Allow Qty Below 0**.

Refer below [Source](http://blog.belvg.com/advanced-inventory-section-management-in-magento-2-0.html) 
Hope this will help you.

Comment: That's true, but that setting is to allow backorders. The main problem with Magento 2 (2.1.2) is that if a quantity is below 0, the product can no longer be saved in the admin due to above JavaScript notice. The problem (in my opinion) is the `validate-digits`-rule: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7401